# How to deploy ML trained model?

Tags: python, html, machine-learning, flask

I am working on a ML project **Credit Card Fraud  Detection**. I have trained the model using **Random Forest Classifier**. The [dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/mlg-ulb/creditcardfraud) used in this project is taken from Kaggle. It contains 31 features, the last feature is used to classify the transaction is fraud or not. Now I want to deploy the model using flask. For which I am following [this](https://medium.datadriveninvestor.com/deploy-your-machine-learning-model-using-flask-made-easy-now-635d2f12c50c) tutorial. But instead of entering data into input fields, I want the user to upload a CSV file with a single record. So, what changes should be made in the code?

`app.py`

```
import numpy as np
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, render_template
import pickle

app = Flask(__name__)
# prediction function 
def ValuePredictor(to_predict_list): 
    to_predict = np.array(to_predict_list).reshape(1, 30) 
    loaded_model = pickle.load(open("model.pkl", "rb")) 
    result = loaded_model.predict(to_predict) 
    return result[0]     
    
@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route('/predict',methods=['POST','GET'])
def predict():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        to_predict_list = request.form.to_dict() 
        to_predict_list = list(to_predict_list.values()) 
        to_predict_list = list(map(float, to_predict_list))
        result = ValuePredictor(to_predict_list)
    if int(result)== 1:
        prediction ='Given transaction is fradulent'
    else:
        prediction ='Given transaction is NOT fradulent'            
    return render_template("index.html", prediction_text = prediction_text) 
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

`index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<!--From https://codepen.io/frytyler/pen/EGdtg-->
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>ML API</title>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arimo' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Hind:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/style.css') }}">
  
</head>

<body>
 <div class="login">
    <h1>Credit Card Fraud Detection</h1>

     <!-- Main Input For Receiving Query to our ML -->
    <form action="{{ url_for('predict')}}"method="post">
        <label for="file">Choose file to upload</label>
    <input type="file" name="file" accept=".csv">
        
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-large">Predict</button>
    </form>

   <br>
   <br>
   {{ prediction_text }}

 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer this:
https://python-bloggers.com/2021/01/practical-guide-build-and-deploy-a-machine-learning-web-app/
This is a guide to create a web app that will take CSV file as input and returns a CSV file with the predictions.